# Default Settings for TextEdit and XtraGrid DevExpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid, textedit

I'm trying devexpress component, so I want to know if is possible to write code for define standard option for TextEdit and XtraGrid.
For Form's theme I write this code in Program.cs:

```
UserLookAndFeel.Default.SetSkinStyle("Office 2007 Blue");
```

So every form have this skin...
Is possible to do something for XtraGrid and TextEdit Options?

Sorry for very bad english..

Example:

```
        dataGrid.OptionsPrint.UsePrintStyles = true;
        dataGrid.OptionsPrint.EnableAppearanceEvenRow = true;
        dataGrid.OptionsPrint.EnableAppearanceOddRow = true;
```

Comment: Completely unclear. What do you meant by *I want to know if is possible to write code for define standard option for TextEdit and XtraGrid*

Comment: So you want `grid` and `textedit` to be in same Skin? By default they will be in same theme only

Comment: I mean I want to set dataGrid.OptionsPrint.UsePrintStyles = true; for ALL GridView in myproject... like I do with skin..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option for what you're asking(AFAIK). but you could extend the `Gridview` and implement it easily.

```
public class MyGridView : GridView
{
    public MyGridView()
    {
        this.OptionsPrint.UsePrintStyles = true;
        this.OptionsPrint.EnableAppearanceEvenRow = true;
        this.OptionsPrint.EnableAppearanceOddRow = true;
    }
}
```

Then use this class all over your project